# How to push data from AWS IoT MQTT broker to a random file in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, mqtt, aws-iot, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have created a rule to forward all messages published to any topic e.g. foo/bar of my AWS IoT core managed MQTT broker to a nested folder in S3 bucket. For that, I am using *key* section. I can send data to nested folder like a/b/c. The problem is - it takes c as destination file and this file gets updated with new data as it arrives. Is there any configuration that I can do to put data in bucket in a new file (with any random name) as it arrives (similar to how it happens when we forward data from firehose to S3)

Comment: Hi, where could I find a tutorial step by step to do that? I am reading the documentation and it is not clear. I

Comment: @zwitterion I don't have any link as such but can summarize the steps as below:

    1. get the broker URL from settings tab of AWS IoT core dashboard

    2. create policies and certificate (under secure tab). attach policy to certificate. Please make sure policy allows capabilities related to iot

    3. create a rule - name the rule. write your query statement.

    4. Add action and choose option of S3 bucket. Select/Create role that have permission to push data into the bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your *key* to use the `newuuid()` function. e.g.

```
a/b/${newuuid()}
```

This will write the data to a file in the *a/b* folder with a filename that is a generated UUID.

The *key* in AWS IoT S3 Actions allow you to use the IoT SQL Reference Functions to form the folder and filename.

The [documentation for the key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-rule-actions.html#s3-rule) states:

> The path to the file where the data is written. For example, if the value of this argument is "${topic()}/${timestamp()}", the topic the message was sent to is "this/is/my/topic,", and the current timestamp is 1460685389, the data is written to a file called "1460685389" in the "this/is/my/topic" folder on Amazon S3.

If you don't want to use a timestamp then you could form the name of the file using other functions such as a [random float](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-rand) (`rand()`), [calculate a hash](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-hash) (`md5()`), a [UUID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-newuuid) (`newuuid()`) or the [trace id of the message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-traceid) (`traceid()`).

Comment: Wow. That really solved it. Thanks. I was trying to define the key from UI and somehow writing the syntax inside "" or making some other mistakes. when I pasteda/b/${newuuid()}, it just did the job. Many thanks and have a great weekend...